# trigger 'change' loops back into function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a survey builder that I have set up to trigger questions based on whether the question is yes or no. For example I have one form that goes like this.

Thanks any feedback would be great. :)

1. Have you recently experienced any technical issues while using our software? YES NO

If `no`, no more questions should be asked, but the last child question pops when it shouldn't, if `yes` the next question should come up and for some reason using the below JavaScript, it returns false for the question but then loops back through again until it is false.

```
$(function(){
  $('body').on('change', '.parent_question select, .parent_question input', function(){
    var child_input = $('[name="' + $(this).data('child-name') + '"]');
    console.log(child_input);
    var child_question = child_input.closest('.survey_answers');
    var trigger_on = $(this).data('trigger-on');
    var show = $(this)[0].selectedIndex == undefined ? ($(this).closest('.survey_answers').find('input').index($(this)) + 1) == trigger_on : $(this)[0].selectedIndex == trigger_on;
    if (show) {
      child_question.show();
    } else {
      child_question.hide();
      child_input.val('');
      child_input.attr('checked', false);
      console.log(child_input);
      child_input.trigger('change');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: So do you want to hide all other questions unless `Yes` has been selected?

Comment: please format your code properly... it looks crap

Comment: Yeah @Twisty that is exactly what I want :)

Comment: the only thing is that I know the child_input.trigger('change'); line is what is making it loop but I'm trying to target only the child input and for some reason any change on the question makes it loop until it returns true.

Comment: Working on it here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/16tw7q3j/

Comment: Thanks @Twisty I appreciate you helping me with this. :)

Comment: So far, only made very minor changes (`$('#survey_page').on()`): https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/16tw7q3j/1/ but this seems to be working the way you described?

Comment: Not yet, I don't want the last question to show on no, I want that to be triggered on the result of the third embedded questions answer only.

Comment: So as I see it, you have 6 questions, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, & 6. A Yes for 1, exposes 2. A Yes 2 for  exposes 3, A No for 3 exposes 4? Am I following the logic right?

Comment: Yeah that is correct :)

Comment: Ok, what exposes 5 or 6?

Comment: those questions stand alone. They are revealed automatically. The other ones are revealed for relevance to the answer.

Comment: Well Actually 5 is shown automatically, and on not at all satisfied should pop the 6 question :)

Comment: 5 and 6 seem to work just fine though.

Comment: All my testing so far has worked with the logic you're suggesting. What am I missing?

Comment: If you reload the page at the beginning, you will see the "have you recently experienced any technical issues while using kadince?" If that answer is yes the the question "Do you feel the issue was resolved in a timely manner?" if no "Any comments you'd like us to know shows up, but I don't want it to show up on no to that first question it should show up only on the answer to the third question.

Comment: Why would a user reload the page? Also this would suggest something is either removing the `.hidden` or triggering `change`.

Comment: Its not when they reload. I was just saying so you could see it from the start.

Comment: I think it is something to do with child_input.trigger('change'); but I need that to clear the child questions input if they select a different answer on the parent question.

Comment: @Twisty do you have any ideas with that? I have tried using triggerHandler instead and it resolves that, but if someone select yes for the first question and then selects yes for the second and then changes the answer for the first question, the third question stays on the page. So I'm using trigger to make sure that when a answer is change make sure the right things are shown but it also shows the wrong question with that :(

Comment: I don't see why we are triggering `change`, and thus creating the loop. I think maybe we should refine the selection to radio buttons and make a second function for the question 4, when a change is made to the `textarea`, so that 5 & 6 are exposed when a users enters a comment.

Comment: well the reason its radio buttons or select is because I have a survey builder on the back end that creates surveys and the team in charge of customer happiness wants the ability to have radio and select but I want 5 exposed and 6 is working correctly, its 4 that is showing if you select no on 1, 2, or 3 but I only want it to show on no for 3

Comment: child_input.attr('checked', false); should be child_input.prop('checked', false); for reference: stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Answer (score 0):

After our comment,s I think I have things working the way you want. No changes to HTML, but the JQuery I used is as follows:

```
$(function() {
  $('#survey_page').on('change',
    '.parent_question select, .parent_question input',
    function() {
      console.log($(this).attr('name') + " selected: " + $(this).val());
      var child_input = $('[name="' + $(this).data('child-name') + '"]');
      //console.log(child_input);
      var child_question = child_input.closest('.survey_answers');
      var trigger_on = $(this).data('trigger-on');
      var show = $(this)[0].selectedIndex == undefined ? ($(this).closest('.survey_answers').find('input').index($(this)) + 1) == trigger_on : $(this)[0].selectedIndex == trigger_on;
      console.log("Show child (" + $(this).data('child-name') + "): " + show);
      if (show) {
        child_question.show();
      } else {
        child_question.hide();
        child_input.val('');
        child_input.attr('checked', false);
        console.log(child_input);
        if (child_input.is("textarea")) {
          console.log("Next item is textarea, triggering change.");
          child_input.trigger('change');
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/16tw7q3j/4/

If the users selects specific answers, conditionally, more questions are exposed. If the users goes back and changes an answer, it should reset the conditions on children item.

I moved the `change` event away from the `body` to `#survey_page`, yet either should work. I also conditionally trigger change if the child input is `textarea`, which I think helps prevent looping. Feel free to test and comment if it's not working as you wanted. Not sure if my test Fiddle matches your environment exactly.

**Update**

This might be overkill at the moment, but it works: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/16tw7q3j/9/

```
$(function() {
  $('body').on('change', '.parent_question select, .parent_question input', function() {
    var current_input_name = $(this).prop('name');
    var current_input_id = parseInt(current_input_name.substring(24, 26));
    var last_input_name = $(".parent_question:last [name^='survey[answers]']").prop('name');
    var last_input_id = parseInt(last_input_name.substring(24, 26));
    console.log("Change " + current_input_name + "/" + last_input_name + ", " + current_input_id + "/" + last_input_id);
    var child_input = $('[name="' + $(this).data('child-name') + '"]');
    var child_question = child_input.closest('.survey_answers');
    var trigger_on = $(this).data('trigger-on');
    var show = $(this)[0].selectedIndex == undefined ? ($(this).closest('.survey_answers').find('input').index($(this)) + 1) == trigger_on : $(this)[0].selectedIndex == trigger_on;
    if (show) {
      child_question.show();
    } else {
      child_question.hide();
      child_input.val('');
      child_input.prop('checked', false);
    }
    for (var i = current_input_id + 2; i <= last_input_id; i++) {
      console.log("Clearing survey[answers][question" + i + "]");
      var nextElem = $("[name='survey[answers][question" + i + "]']");
      nextElem.parents("div.survey_answers").hide();
      nextElem.val('');
      nextElem.prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
```

I create the scope between the current changed element, skip the child, since that is handled conditionally already, and clear out all the other selections.

Comment: That is very similar to my solution right now but that brings up a separate issue. For instance in our example, if you go to the link and you answer question 1 with 'yes' and then question 2 with 'yes'. Now go back and change answer 1 to 'no'. That should clear the value for question 2 and question 3 but it only clears and hides question 2.

Comment: So then we need to clear all inputs that are NOT the one that was just changed, correct?

Comment: Yeah :) I'm not sure how to do that in javascript

Comment: Well all inputs tied to that question we don't want to clear 5 and 6

Comment: `child_input.attr('checked', false);` should be  `child_input.prop('checked', false);`  for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: Well that works unless I have created multiple questions. The problem is it's a survey that will have multiple first level questions and then child questions based on that. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, and this was designed to be more flexible. Since I do not know the whole scope, I could not know what else would be done. If you want to make a Fiddle that has an example of all the types of elements, then that would have been easier. This is only working with what data I could gleam.

Comment: okay. @Twisty I created a jsfiddle with more questions. you can find it here. https://jsfiddle.net/jorden15/9yz45bz8/

Comment: @JordenTSchreck this Fiddle appears to have questions 1, 2, & 3, and then repeats question 1 and 2.

Comment: Yes it does, but they were generated from my survey builder and they have different names for the second rounds of questions. I only created the same question because it is one of my more in depth questions they want to ask so I need the jquery to work with that. @Twisty

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $('body').on('change', '.parent_question select, .parent_question input', function(){
    var child_input = $('[name="' + $(this).data('child-name') + '"]');
    var child_question = child_input.closest('.survey_answers');
    var trigger_on = $(this).data('trigger-on');
    var show = $(this)[0].selectedIndex == undefined ? ($(this).closest('.survey_answers').find('input').index($(this)) + 1) == trigger_on : $(this)[0].selectedIndex == trigger_on;
    if (show) {
      child_question.show();
    } else {
      child_question.hide();
      child_input.val('');
      child_input.prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
```

This code solves the issue I was having but now I want to clear all child_questions values and hide all child questions if someone changes there answer. @Twisty any ideas?

Comment: Trying to find a way to select all the other inputs based on the element that was changed, and then can use `$.each()` to iterate them all and remove any selections.

Comment: Yeah, I still haven't been able to come up with a solution for this. :/